# MapView zoom to usercordinate as centre

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

I have a map view which shows users location. The user location is shown as centre of mapview. But when the mapview is zoomed i have to show the user location as centre. But currently it doesn't show that. The user location moves away from the centre. How to show the user location in the centre position even if the map is zoomed. I have used KVO notification but when zoomed the function zoom out the map and plot users location in the centre. But i dont want to zoom it out. Any help is appreciated. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure i understand what you're trying to do but you could try using the

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated` delegate method of MKMapView.

In there you could play with the span value and check whether the map has been zoomed or not. Then you could center the map to your user's current location.

Or you could use the

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

delegate method to center the map before the region is changed.